# clean json output in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a customized code as a plugin using hooks in wordpress (latest version). I also have some customized tables in the database. I am querying some data from the database and output the array using JSON. The output comes fine but since it is based on hooks the output comes with a full page (html heading and body). What I need is to only output the JSON code so my mobile app can understand the code.

here is an example:

my code for the hook:

```
    <?php

    $getPosts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM gc_posts WHERE 
    userid=$organization");
    foreach($getPosts as $getPosts){
    $imageLocation = $target_dir . $getPosts->image;

    $myContents->title = "$getPosts->title";
    $myContents->description = "$getPosts->description";
    $myContents->image = "$imageLocation";


}
wp_send_json($myContents);
```

And this is the current output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<script>(func
...
<body>
...
{"title":"Museum","description":"Open from 10 am to 10 pm","image":"1_1527407746.jpg"}
...
```

While what I am looking for is only the JSON code like:

```
{"title":"Museum","description":"Open from 10 am to 10 pm","image":"1_1527407746.jpg"}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing some code, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Added my code. Please check if you can help!

Comment: The problem is the URL you are using is interpreted by WordPress as a request for a HTML document so WordPress wraps your output in an HTML document. WordPress supports an AJAX entry point for data only requests. You should use it to return JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks to magenta for answering this question.

I followed magenta answe and instead of using the normal post page URL, I used the following:

```
[http://yourwebsite.com]/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?[your_action_action_function_name]
```

and I added an action in my plugin so this would be allowed:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_action_action_function_name', 'your_action_action_function_name');
```